# Adaptive Paypal Payment Error Code: 579017

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am using delayed chained Paypal payment systems. I got an error like

> *Detailed Error Message: The amount for the primary receiver must be greater than or equal to the total of other chained receiver
>   amountsError Code: 579017Error Severity: ErrorError Domain:
>   PLATFORMError Category: Application*

How to send the amount the primary receiver gets an amount less than the secondary receiver

My scenario is The primary receiver gets an amount from the sender and gets some amount for service and send the amount to the secondary receiver.

for example the user books an ticket means the site owner get the full amount from the receiver and take his service charge as some percentage and send the remaining amount to the property owner I used delayed chained payment

my code is

```
$receiverEmailArray = array(
        'johnwewe9340_biz@gmail.com',
        'jameswewe9546_per@gmail.com',
        '',
        '',
        ''
        );

// TODO - specify the receiver amounts as the amount of money, for example, '5' or '5.55'
//        remove or set to an empty string the array entries for receivers that you do not have
$receiverAmountArray = array(
        '10',
        '100',
        '',
        '',
        ''
        );

// TODO - Set ONLY 1 receiver in the array to 'true' as the primary receiver, and set the
//        other receivers corresponding to those indicated in receiverEmailArray to 'false'
//        make sure that you do NOT specify more values in this array than in the receiverEmailArray
$receiverPrimaryArray = array(
        'true',
        'false'
        );

// TODO - Set invoiceId to uniquely identify the transaction associated with each receiver
//        set the array entries with value for receivers that you have
//        each of the array values must be unique across all Pay calls made by the caller's API credentials
$receiverInvoiceIdArray = array(
        '',
        '',
        '',
        '',
        '',
        ''
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

The primary has to receive the full amount and the secondary only the amount they are supposed to get.
So if the total amount is $100.00 and the primary keeps 10%
the primary gets 100.00 and the secondary gets 90.00.